# Django validate_unique restricts update/patch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this model which is serialized via DRF

```
class Orders(models.Model):
accession = models.CharField(max_length=20)
testcode = models.ForeignKey(TestCodes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tcodes') # 
testName = models.ForeignKey(TestCodes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='testname', related_name='tnames')
method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default='NGS')
custName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
testSite = models.CharField(max_length=50)
procedure = models.ForeignKey(Workflows, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

where I'm trying to make the accession and testcode fields combination unique to prevent user from creating the same accession with the same testcode

```
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    qs = Orders.objects.filter(accession=self.accession)
    if qs.filter(testcode=self.testcode).exists():
       raise ValidationError('Accession must be unique per testcode')



def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
 
        self.validate_unique()

        super(Orders, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

it works well but if I try to patch or update other fields it raises the validation error 'Accession must be unique per testcode'
is there a workaround for this issue

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator

from .models import Orders
from testcodes.models import TestCodes

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    testcode = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=False,
        queryset=TestCodes.objects.all(),
        slug_field='testcode'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = '__all__'

        # validators = [
        #     UniqueTogetherValidator(
        #         queryset=Orders.objects.all(),
        #         fields=['accession', 'testcode']
        #     )
        # ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle that directly in the model, by adding a unique_together property in the Meta class, as follows:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    accession = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    testcode = models.ForeignKey(TestCodes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tcodes') # 
    testName = models.ForeignKey(TestCodes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='testname', related_name='tnames')
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default='NGS')
    custName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    testSite = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    procedure = models.ForeignKey(Workflows, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("accession", "testcode")
```

......

Comment: I tried that it gives 
 `{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "The fields accession, testcode must make a unique set."
    ]
}`

Comment: Could you show the full code for your serializer please.

Comment: Hi i have added that in the post